# how to prove $\sqrt{3}+i\sqrt{5}$ is algebraic??

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

How to prove $\sqrt{3}+i\sqrt{5}$ is algebraic??

I studied one result sum of two algebraic numbers are algebraic so that's why they are algebraic but I am not sure about the result...please help me anyone

Comment: Do you know the *definition* of algebraic numbers?

Comment: yes a number satisfies the polynomial over integer coefficients

Comment: I agree that the result that the sum of algebraic numbers is algebraic (and even more so the result that the sum of algebraic integers is an algebraic integer) is quite baffling. I am not sure if understanding this example will help understanding the general case, but luckily some posts on that case appear automatically in the side bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\sqrt3+i\sqrt5$.

Thus,
$$(x-\sqrt3)^2=-5$$

If you solve you will get $$x^2-2\sqrt{3}x+8=0$$ but here one coefficient is irrational.
Now, write $$x^2+8=2\sqrt3x$$ and use squaring.

Can you end it now?

Comment: if you solve you will get $x^2-2\sqrt{3}x+8=0$ but here the coefficient is irrational so it can't be algebraic

Comment: @Hemshan Now, write $x^2+8=2\sqrt3x$ and use squaring.

Comment: yeah ok I got it ..

Comment: @Hemshan Good luck!

Comment: Take this way, it may show $x = \sqrt{a} + i\sqrt{b}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ is algebraic number about equation $x^4 + 2(b - a)x^2 + (b + a)^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$x=\sqrt3+i\sqrt5$ is a root of the polynomial $x^4 + 4x^2 +64$, hence it's algebraic.

One way to get there is to use the  third Binomial formula:
$$
(x + \sqrt3+i\sqrt5)(x- \sqrt3 - i\sqrt5) = x^2 + 2 - 2i \sqrt{15}$$
and again
$$
(x^2 + 2 - 2i \sqrt{15})(x^2 + 2 + 2i \sqrt{15}) = x^4 + 4x^2 +64
$$

Indeed this works with all  expressions of the type $x=\sqrt{k}+i\sqrt{n}$ with integers $k$ and $n$.